# Ordering links in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, hyperlink

I have a list containing some links: ["http://link1.rar", "http://link1.rev","http://link2.rar","http://link2.rev"]
Is there a way to sort them, in order to look like:
["http://link1.rar", "http://link2.rar", "http://link1.rev", "http://link2.rev"]

I've tried with this:

```
def order(x):
    if "rar" not in x:
        return x
    else:
        return ""

new_links = sorted(links, key=order)
```

But in this way, rev links are sorted from the highest.

Comment: are all numbers between 1 and 9? If you have a number 10 in there, that'll screw the sorting.

Comment: You are right, another reason why I'm asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve according to multiple criteria: first, the file extension; then, the whole string.

The usual trick to sort according to multiple criteria is to use a tuple as the key. Tuples are sorted in lexicographical order, which means the first criterion is compared first; and in case of a tie, the second criterion is compared.

For instance, the following key returns a tuple such as `(False, 'http://link1.rar')` or `(True, 'http://link1.rev')`:

```py
new_links = sorted(links, key=lambda x: ('rar' not in x, x))
```

Alternatively, you could use `str.rsplit` to split the string on the last `'.'` and get a tuple such as `('http://link1', 'rev')`. Since you want the extension to be the first criterion, use slicing `[::-1]` to reverse the order of the tuple:

```py
new_links = sorted(links, key=lambda x: x.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[::-1])
```

Note that using `rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)` to split on the last `'.'` is a bit of a hack. If the filename contains a double extension, such as `'.tar.gz'`, only the last extension will be isolated.

One last point to consider: numbers in strings. As long as your strings contain only single digits, such as `'1'` or `'2'`, sorting the strings will work as you expect. However, if you have a `'link10'` somewhere in there, the order might not be the one you expect: lexicographically, `'link10'` comes before `'link2'`, because the first character of `'10'` is `'1'`. In that case, I refer you to this related question: [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)